# Creating Dynamic ImageViews and populating via HTTP GET using Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Just a quick one.

I've got a TableView that is being populated by a HTTP GET request to an API. It returns a mix of text, images, movies etc using Appcelerator on both iOS and Android.

I've got everything laid out and working fine, but when I cycle through the images only the last item in my tableView gets populated with an image, rather than all of them.

I suspect it's because the imageView doesn't have a unique name. I'm having to do a request within the for loop as thats the way the API is setup, each download has to be requested separately.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

function getMedia(itemID, mediaType) is where I do the download an apply it to the imageView.

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, itemID + '.png');
f.write(this.responseData); // write to the file

postImage.image = f.nativePath;
```

Here is my code:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onerror: function() {

        // hide the table
        exploreTableView.visible = false;

    },
    onload: function() {
        // parse the retrieved data, turning it into a JavaScript object
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info(json);


        // don't build the table if no posts have been made
        if (json.length == 0) {

            tableData = [];

            //holdingLabel.visible = true;
            exploreTableView.visible = false;

        } else {

            //holdingLabel.visible = false;
            exploreTableView.visible = true;

            for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                // check if this has been deleted, if so, skip it and move on!
                if (json[i].status == "alive") {


                    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                        height: 'auto',
                        bottom: 10,
                        selectedBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        //editable: deleteRow,
                        layout: 'vertical'
                    });




                    var postView = Ti.UI.createView({
                        top: 0,
                        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
                        layout: 'vertical'
                    });

                    // detect what media we have


                    // show an image if there is an image uploaded
                    if (json[i].type == "image/jpeg") {
                        var postImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                            image: 'images/bcell-square-picture-pre-load.png',
                            defaultImage: 'bcell-square-picture-pre-load.png'
                        });

                        postView.add(postImage);

                        getMedia(json[i]._id, "photo");
                    }


                    row.add(postView);

                    tableData.push(row);

                    // set some variables to access
                    row.itemID = json[i]._id;


                    function getMedia(itemID, mediaType) {
                        // let's fetch the media for the post
                        if (mediaType == "photo") {
                            var url = "https://myapi.com/";
                        }



                        var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
                            onload: function() {
                                // handle the response
                                Ti.API.info('Media: ' + this.responseData);

                                var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, itemID + '.png');
                                f.write(this.responseData); // write to the file

                                postImage.image = f.nativePath;

                            }
                        });

                        xhr.open("GET", url);
                        // set the header for the correct JSON format
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("xxx", Ti.App.Properties.getString('token'));
                        // send the data to the server
                        xhr.send();
                    }



                }



            }



        }

        exploreTableView.setData(tableData);

    }



});

xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("xxx", Ti.App.Properties.getString('token'));

// send the data to the server
xhr.send();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are downloading the images in a different function `postImage` is linking to the last element because the loop is already done when the images appear. It should work when you pass `postImage` as a parameter to `getMedia`

Comment: Can you explain how that works in code? Not sure I follow

Comment: `getMedia(json[i]._id, "photo", postImage);` and then `function getMedia(itemID, mediaType, postImage) {...}` so inside the getMedia you a using a accessing the proper postImage